# How can I multiply if the custom expression contains keyword with in the formula?

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to achieve a calculation in Spotfire. Where I am trying below expression but it giving me a different result.

```
formula:
Sum(case  when [wip]=1 then 1 else 0 end) / Sum((case  when [fpassed]=1 then 1 else 0 end) * 1.0) * 0.85) + (
Sum(case  when [recover]=1 then 1 else 0 end) / Sum((case  when [fpassed]=1 then 1 else 0 end) * 1.0) * 
(Sum(case  when [fpassed]=1 then 1 else 0 end) / Sum((case  when [total_input]=1 then 1 else 0 end) * 1.0))) as [PROJECTED YIELD]


VALUES:
88.73=  Sum(case  when [wip]=1 then 1 else 0 end) / Sum((case  when [mlb_passed]=1 then 1 else 0 end) * 1.0) * 0.85) + (
Sum(case  when [fg_recovery]=1 then 1 else 0 end) / Sum((case  when [mlb_passed]=1 then 1 else 0 end) * 1.0)

54.03 = Sum(case  when [fpassed]=1 then 1 else 0 end) / Sum((case  when [total_input]=1 then 1 else 0 end) * 1.0))


47.9 should be the projected yield but the result coming from the calculation is 49.0
```

Can someone help me here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is closed. Just made some adjustment in the formula and its already working.

Comment: if you post your solution it could help other people in the future :)

Comment: just added  * 100.  the Sum(case  when [wip]=1 then 1 else 0 end) / Sum((case  when [fpassed]=1 then 1 else 0 end) * 1.0 * 100) * 0.85)